# OroCommerce: Disable order edit by some conditions

Tags: orocommerce

Is it possible to disable order editing when some conditions (like order status is shipped, but may be smtl else) are met?

Or disable LineItems editing but allow to edit order info?

Tried to add this lines to my current active order workflow and got nothing:

```
        entity_restrictions:
            test:
                attribute: entity
                field: customer_notes
```

tried to add this to one of workflow steps but again nothig

```
            entity_acl:
                update: false
                delete: false
```

**entity_restrictions** and **entity_acl** are not used in any workflow.yml of oro bundles so is that functionality really implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didnt found how to disable order edit via workflow like is was suggested previously here is the working way how to disable that via action configuration:

```
#MyBundle/Resources/config/oro/actions.yml
operations:
  my_oro_order_edit
    extends: UPDATE                         # this is for keeping all other properties same as in default
    substitute_operation: UPDATE            # replace UPDATE operation with current one
    entities: ['Oro\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\Order'] # replacement will occur only if this operation will be matched by entity
    for_all_entities: false
    replace:
      - preconditions
    preconditions:
      '@equal': [$internalStatus.id, 'open']
```

This substitutes UPDATE operation for order with my_oro_order_edit where conditions to allow UPDATE are changed - so edit button in order view page and orders grid will appear only for 'Open' orders. However this affects only buttons and its still possible to open order edit via direct link which should be prohibited using access rules

Answer (score 1):

From the built-in features, you can use the workflow engine with the entity restrictions to make some form fields read-only based on conditions: https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities-data-management/workflows/configuration-reference/#entity-restrictions-configuration

Or create an access rule to hide the editing button and return 403 code for the editing page when conditions are met: https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/security/access-rules/#backend-security-bundle-access-rules

Comment: I dont see any workflow related to order where I can change conditions for order editing, do I missing something? Eg I understand how to add restrictions for opportunity which has workflow, but how to do that for order which is probably implemented without workflow engine?

Comment: You can create your own workflow for the Order entity

Comment: And how can new workflow affect existing order edit?

Comment: With the entity restrictions, you can make some form fields in the existing order edit for read-only based on conditions.

Comment: Updated start post with the entity_restrictions lines which didnt helped at all, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you've reloaded the workflow after changing the configuration. https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities-data-management/workflows/configuration-reference/#configuration-loading

Comment: Absolutely sure, I even made some changes in messages and reactivated workflow to be sure that it was updated but customer notes in order still editable and saved ok.
Actually I need to make order not editable only on the last step of workflow and tried to use entity_acl on that step too but nothing changed and order is always editable